# Vue 3 createApp not defined in Chrome

Tags: vue.js, google-chrome-devtools, vuejs3

When using Vue 3 and the new `createApp` Chrome does not recognize it. In my main.js I have:

```js
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'

createApp(App).mount('#app')
```

I tested with a newly generated vue-cli app and it does not work.

The Chrome Vue devtools does not recognize any localhost app and typing `Vue` in the console inside a Vue app says this: `Uncaught ReferenceError: Vue is not defined at <anonymous>:1:1`

Comment: Are you running the `Vue CLI` service? (with this command: `npm run serve`)

Answer (score 3):

There are two ways to run a new Vue 3 project which has been created with the Vue CLI.

1. Start the dev server by running `npm run serve` and open a browser to `http://127.0.0.1:8080/`.
2. Create a `build` by running `npm run build` and then open `dist/index.html` in your browser.

If you want access to your Vue app within the browser console, you could do the following:

```js
import { createApp } from 'vue';
import App from './App.vue';


const app = createApp(App);

// now you can see `vueApp` within the browser console
window.vueApp = app;

app.mount('#app');
```

Comment: This code does work, but chrome Vue devtools still say: `Vue.js not detected` and typing `Vue` inside the console this throws the error

Comment: @VictorMotogna You may be using the devtools for Vue 2. The extension for Vue 3 is different: https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/installation.html#vue-devtools - and try typing `vueApp` in the console, not `Vue` (if you're using the code I posted).

Comment: Yes, this was the problem. Thanks!